# How to install primitives/lens with GHC 7.8.3 on mac os 10.8.5

Tags: haskell

I finally managed to install GHC 7.8.2 and when I try to lens install `lens` it fails because it can't install `primitive`. If I try to install primitive on it's own I get the following error message:

```
Resolving dependencies... Configuring primitive-0.5.3.0... Building
primitive-0.5.3.0... Preprocessing library primitive-0.5.3.0... 0 
clang             0x00000001010536f2 main + 17107682 1  clang         
0x0000000101053b79 main + 17108841 2  libsystem_c.dylib
0x00007fff8c4b090a _sigtramp + 26 3  libsystem_c.dylib
0x0000000000000039 _sigtramp + 18446603338162435913 4  clang          
0x0000000100657327 main + 6637335 5  clang            
0x0000000100656618 main + 6633992 6  clang            
0x000000010065640b main + 6633467 7  clang            
0x0000000100655521 main + 6629649 8  clang            
0x00000001004c47fe main + 4987886 9  clang            
0x0000000100050d6a main + 319834 10 clang            
0x000000010004be8a main + 299642 11 clang            
0x0000000100758969 main + 7691609 12 clang            
0x0000000100751368 main + 7661400 13 clang            
0x0000000100044c01 main + 270321 14 clang            
0x0000000100019ae2 main + 93906 15 clang            
0x0000000100018748 main + 88888 16 clang            
0x0000000100006438 main + 14376 17 clang            
0x0000000100002e97 main + 647 18 clang             0x0000000100002c04
19 clang             0x0000000000000051 Stack dump:
0.      Program arguments: /usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10
```

etc ...

What can I do?

Comment: It's possible `primitive` isn't compatible with clang. It does a lot of architecture-specific stuff. A quick look at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/haskell/primitive/issues) finds [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/primitive/issues/8) suggesting that primitive doesn't build with clang.

Comment: Is there any workarkound. It's seem using gcc works. Is there a way I can tell cabal to use gcc instead of clang ?

Comment: @mb14 Try `CC=/usr/bin/gcc cabal install primitive`

Comment: if this works please make it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solved the problem by using the [ghc-clang-wrapper](https://www.haskell.org/platform/ghc-clang-wrapper) and modifying the `settings` in the GHC installation directory. That's not ideal but works.

To install `ghc-clang-wrapper`, follows the instructions provided with it.
Then , find the installation directory of ghc and modify the `setting` file.
Mine was in `usr/local/lib/ghc-7.8.2/settings` and modify the "C compiler command" line to "/usr/bin/ghc-clang-wrapper" (or wherever you installed `ghc-clang-wrapper`).

I haven't tried Jakub solution but it's probably better.